# CakePHP 2.2 find returns empty data even if query matches results

Tags: cakephp, model, find

I have a fresh baked (with bake console) project in which I have 2 models behaving differently when I call model->find function.

UsersController

```php
public function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
```

WordsController

```php
public function index() {
    $this->Word->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('words', $this->paginate());
}
```

Query (DebugKit)

```sql
SELECT `Word`.`*` FROM `words` AS `Word` WHERE `Word`.`iniziale` = 'A' AND `Word`.`pubblicata` = '1' ORDER BY `Word`.`parola` ASC LIMIT 10
Affected 10 
Num rows 10
```

In both cases the query inspected has affected rows, but the WordsController doesn't return any results if I debug the paginate() result, while the Users one gives correctly.

Word model has no relations, and I tried to change the model name to Term, obtaining the same result.

I tried also to downgrade CakePHP core to 2.1.4. Nothing.

Are there any possible causes to this problem? Is Word some kind of reserved keyword? How can this be debugged?

Comment: You said you had the same problem with "Term" as you did with "Word", right?  That would nullify your question about the word "Word" being protected...etc

Comment: Paste the code you're using in the view to display the results?  And paste your debug code?

Comment: In view I have only a debug($words);

Comment: do you have entry in your DB?

Comment: Yes, both tables have hundreds of rows. As I wrote, the query returns rows but Cake does not recognizes them...

Comment: Have you added afterFind callbacks or anything in the model that could alter the data? Are you using any behaviors? Show your model and your `AppModel`

Comment: Oh snap! Had I seen the "hidden" comment by @tigrang it would have saved me 3+ hours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had in the words table (UTF8), some texts containing special characters like àòèéìù. Cake removed all the result containing these characters. I tried replacing "è" with "e" and magically the record was available in Cake!

Hope my 5 hours of headache will help someone else!

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer follows that accepted. You should set the encoding in your DB configuration:
In my conf I had:

```
public $default = array(
     'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
                'persistent' => false,
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'login' => 'giuseppe',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'database' => 'db'
                'prefix' => '',
                //'encoding' => 'utf8',

    );
```

Do you see the encoding key? Try to uncomment or set it to the correct encoding, and voila!

Comment: This solved my problem. I had blank results too. I've uncommented it and set it to 'utf8' and records now are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from a comment in the question above..

Check your model and AppModel and see whether there is any afterFind(). The afterFind call must return the $results dataset at the end.

```
function afterFind($results, $primary = false)  {
    //some code here..
    return $results; //I had this commented out for some reason
    //and it generated the same issue.
}
```